# Wrong orientation after UIActivityViewController's Markup is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rotation, uikit

The app is set to support portrait, landscape left and landscape right orientations and iPhone only. The view controller from which the UIActivityViewController is shown doesn't support rotation and must be in portrait orientation only. When the Markup PDF is open it gets its supported orientations from the app and rotates. The problem comes when the user tries to dismiss the Markup view and presses "Done" in landscape. Then the parent view controller is shown also in landscape event tho it supports only portrait orientation and should not autorotate.

I made a bug Radar with Apple's feedback assistant.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        [.portrait]
    }

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "")
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["text to share....", formatter], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Happens only on iOS13 and later.

Comment: are you still facing this issue? if not, how did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Couples of things you are doing wrong, you must return false from this `shouldAutorotate` also this variable also return orientation. `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. replace your code with this.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [.portrait]
}

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "")
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["text to share....", formatter], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityViewController, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: That's the same! It doesn't solve the problem. Please note that the example is in Swift 5.1. If you have a single-expression function you can skip the `return` ([SE-0255](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md))